# Is this function(operator overloading) threadsafe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, operators

Here's the code:

```
ElementType& operator[] (int key)
{
    //something like boost::mutex::scoped_lock
    MutexLockType lock();

    if(key < 0 || key > m_bound)
        throw std::range_error("access out of bound");

    return m_elements[key];
}
```

Comment: No it isn't - how do you know that the element isn't removed the moment your lock's released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not because you have allowed a reference the element to leak out of the function and away from the safety of the lock.

What's more, thread-safety questions are a little hard to answer without a harder specification of just [what flavour of thread-safety](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx) you are desirest.  At the very least you would need to show us every other access of `m_elements` and `m_bound`.

Comment: Indeed a very good answer. I was just caught by that and provided a complete wrong answer ... didn't clearly see it.

Answer (score 1):

In this exact example you would be even more surprised when you realize that there is no lock at all, just a declaration of a lock() function that returns a LockType.

Not that that it would have helped with a lock anyway.

Comment: This might be better as a comment than an answer, but I upvoted it anyway, because it needed to be pointed out (and is a nasty surprise for non-greybeards in C).